# Concerning $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{\langle x^2-1, yz \rangle}$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, commutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{\langle x^2-1, yz \rangle}$.

For convenience, I will write $x,y,z \in R$ instead of $\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z}$.

In $R[X,Y]$, take $A=(x+iy)X+yY$, $B=yX+(x-iy)Y$, $C=zX$.

We have: 
$\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=A_XB_Y-A_YB_X=(x+iy)(x-iy)-yy=x^2-i^2y^2-y^2=x^2+y^2-y^2=x^2=1$
$\operatorname{Jac}(A,C)=A_XC_Y-A_YC_X=(x+iy)0-yz=-yz=0$.

> Is it true that $C \notin R[A]$?

I think/hope that the answer is yes (though I may be wrong):

Otherwise, $C \in R[A]$ so there exists $h(t) \in R[t]$ such that 
$C=h(A)$. Since $\deg(C)=\deg(A)=1$, it follows that $h$ must be of degree $1$,
so $h(t)=\lambda t + \mu$ for some $\lambda, \mu \in R$.

Therefore, $C=h(A)$ becomes $zX=\lambda A + \mu= \lambda ((x+iy)X+yY)+ \mu =\lambda(x+iy)X+\lambda yY+\mu$.

Then we must have:
**(i)** $z=\lambda(x+iy)$; **(ii)** $0=\lambda y$; **(iii)** $0=\mu$.

Now, **(ii)** implies (if I am not wrong) that $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=z$.

But each of these two options contradicts **(i)**:
The first option yields $z=\lambda(x+iy)=0(x+iy)=0$,
and the second option yields $z=\lambda(x+iy)=z(x+iy)$, so
$z(1-x-iy)=z-z(x+iy)=0$.
(I think that $z(1-x-iy)=z(1-x)-izy=z(1-x)-i0=z(1-x)$ is not zero).

> Am I missing something trivial?

Thank you very much!

---

**Motivation:** Actually, it seems (but again I may be wrong) that the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture in $R[X,Y]$,
$R=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{\langle x^2-1, yz \rangle}$, is false:

Just take $A=(x+iy)X+yY$, $B=yX+(x-iy)Y$.
We have seen above that $\operatorname{Jac}(A,B)=1$.

It seems that $R[A,B] \subsetneq R[X,Y]$, so $(X,Y) \mapsto (A,B)$ is not an automorphism of $R[X,Y]$.

Moreover, if indeed $R[A,B] \subsetneq R[X,Y]$, then [Proposition 1.1.12](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=wKJqqd8t8KUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) implies that the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture in $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ is false..

It remains to show that $R[A,B] \subsetneq R[X,Y]$. I am not sure yet how to prove this (if this is true..). Observe that $zA=z(x+iy)X+zyY=z(x+iy)X$
and $zB=zyX+z(x-iy)Y=z(x-iy)Y$.

> It seems impossible to obtain $X$ and $Y$; am I right?

Thank you very much again!

Comment: Unfortunately, I had an error and $C \in R[A]$.. The correct argument is that (ii) implies that $\lambda=z \epsilon$, for an appropriate $\epsilon \in R$, for example. $\epsilon=x-iy$. Then $\lambda=z(x-iy)$ and we get that $\lambda A=\lambda((x+iy)X+yY)=\lambda (x+iy)X+\lambda yY=z(x-iy)(x+iy)X+z(x-iy)yY=z(x^2-i^2y^2)X+zy(x-iy)Y=z(x^2+y^2)X+0(x-iy)Y=z(1+y^2)X+0Y=(z+zy^2)X=(z+0)X=zX=C$

Comment: $(X,Y) \mapsto (A,B)$ is an automorphism with inverse $(x,y) \mapsto ((x-iy)X-yY,-yX+(x+iy)Y)$. Notice that, for example, $X$ is in the image of $(x,y) \mapsto (A,B)$, since $X=(x-iy)A-yB$.